# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugUnitTestKotlin'

Tags: android, mockito, mockito-kotlin

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run my mock test in Android

`Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugUnitTestKotlin'.

> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugUnitTestKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugUnitTestCompileClasspath'.
> > Could not find org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0.
> Required by:
> project :app`

Here is my gradle files

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.resturants'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.resturants"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    //navigation
    def navigation_version = "2.7.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    //Add viewmodel library
    def lifecycle_version = "2.7.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    //Add coroutine library
    def coroutine_version = '1.4.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutine_version"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutine_version"

    // retrofit
    def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    // Location Services
    def location_version = "21.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$location_version"

    //hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

    //Glide
    def glide_version = "4.16.0"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"

    //core:arch:testing
    def core_arch_test_version = "2.2.0"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$core_arch_test_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$core_arch_test_version"

    //mock webserver
    def mock_web_server_version = "4.12.0"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:$mock_web_server_version"

    //mockito
    def mockito_version = "3.6.0"
    def mockito_kotlin_version = "2.2.0"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito_version"
    testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:$mockito_kotlin_version"

    //turbine
    def turbine_version = "1.0.0"
    testImplementation "app.cash.turbine:turbine:$turbine_version"
}
```

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.20"
    ext.hilt_version = "2.42"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I want to run my test case but I got stucked for this issue. May anyone please help me on it

Answer (score 0):

Error seems to be that it can't find the dependency `org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0`:

> Could not find org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0

The mockito package was [renamed](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/commit/e740c576e46b2391c3a7b9a9394949cc041a81e7) to `org.mockito.kotlin` only on version 2.2.7.

So you have two options:

1. Change this dependency in your `build.gradle` to:

```
testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:$mockito_kotlin_version"
```

2. Update the mockito version to 2.2.7 or above:

```
def mockito_kotlin_version = "2.2.7"
```

---

Version list for `com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin`: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2/mockito-kotlin

Version list for `org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin`: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mockito.kotlin/mockito-kotlin